# How to store matrices within a matrix in Python like on MATLAB?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix

I'm aware that MATLAB has a function to store 2D matrices in array cells, but how can I do this on Python? I need to store 4X4 matrices in each column of a 1X5 array. Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything yet?  It should be pretty straight forward honestly.

Comment: I couldn't really find any examples for something similar to my scenario. I need to store 5 4X4 matrices in a 1X5 matrix. Is this simple? Apologies as I'm quite new to Python.

Comment: A lot depends on what you want to do with it afterwards.  Generally you just want a `(1, 5, 4, 4)` -shaped array - most "matrix" operations in `numpy` (like `np.matmul`) broadcast over the last two dimensions.

Comment: Maybe look up list of lists, or nested numpy arrays

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible you can build array for each 4x4 matrix and create another matrix where you can reference 5 different 4x4 matrix.

```
a = np.array([[0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0]])
```

create 5 different array like this as per your requirement and then finally reference them all in one array.

```
mat = np.block([[a],[b],[c],[d],[e]])
```

try something similar and you will find your expected results. refer documentation of array and block form numpy.

Answer (score 0):

While MATLAB matrices are close to `numpy` arrays, the equivalent of `cell` is ambiguous.

One option is a list, especially when the cell is (1,5) shape, the size 1 dimension just being an artifact of MATLAB's "everything is 2d".

Another is object dtype array.  Like a list, the elements of such array are references to objects else where in memory.  This is what `scipy.io.loadmat` uses when loading a MATLAB .mat file.  But creating such an array can be tricky, especially if all the component arrays have the same shape.

Yet another option is to make a high-dimension array, e.g. (1,5,4,4).  There was a time when MATLAB only allowed 2d, but `numpy` has allowed this from the beginning.  Remember in `numpy` the leading dimensions are outermost (with the default 'C' ordering).

```
In [407]: alist = [np.ones((2,2),int) for _ in range(3)]
In [408]: alist
Out[408]: 
[array([[1, 1],
        [1, 1]]),
 array([[1, 1],
        [1, 1]]),
 array([[1, 1],
        [1, 1]])]

In [409]: arr = np.array(alist)
In [410]: arr
Out[410]: 
array([[[1, 1],
        [1, 1]],

       [[1, 1],
        [1, 1]],

       [[1, 1],
        [1, 1]]])
In [411]: arr.shape
Out[411]: (3, 2, 2)

In [412]: arr1 = np.empty(3, object)
In [413]: arr1
Out[413]: array([None, None, None], dtype=object)
In [414]: arr1[:] = alist
In [415]: arr1
Out[415]: 
array([array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1]]), array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1]]),
       array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1]])], dtype=object)
```